# I want to target iPhone only (not iPad) using Phonegap

Tags: iphone, xcode, cordova

I want to set the iPhone the only device family available to install my app in XCODE (actually at the AppStore) but - at the AppStore - it says that it can be installed on iPhone and iPad devices;

The App is not optimized to run on a iPad :/ I'm using Phonegap in this project btw.

Note: I do have - under project settings: "Target Device Family : iPhone"

Any ideas how to fix (set) this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot prevent an iPhone application from running on an iPad. It just cannot be done at the moment, there are no special flags for it AFAIK. Most users won't be confused anyway, as iPad (specific or universal) apps are clearly marked as such on the App Store, and are easily distinguished from apps designed only for iPhone.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Julio, I didnt know that :/ I thought that iPhone specific apps couldn't be installed on iPads. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome! Also please tick my answer as valid if you think it was helpful  :)